# Google Recaptcha Styling in Sitecore Form

Tags: sitecore-forms

I am quite new to styling and CSS. On my page, Google recaptcha is going out of the form. I want to hide the blue area and only show the white portion of recaptcha on the form. When anyone hovers over it, it should expand and that too inside the form. Also, how can I fix the position of recaptcha on the form. Right now, its position is moving. I also need help with how to make it responsive? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: At a minimum you will need to provide the HTML that is being used, together with any relevant CSS. A link to a live page showing the issue would be better. As it is, you have not provided enough information to allow people to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to set the position property of the reCAPTCHA element to "relative" or "absolute" as needed and Please try the following to check if  it works.

```
 .grecaptcha-badge {visibility: hidden!important;}
```

Furthermore, there is a similar & detailed approach for your reference, hope it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44543157/how-to-hide-the-google-invisible-recaptcha-badge